# How set permanent heroku directory permission

Tags: heroku

I am deploying an app to Heroku and give it permission to access upload folder. My problem is that it's resetting to a default permission when I quit Heroku bash and restart it. I want this permission to persist. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. When you run heroku bash, it creates one-off dyno with your application code, so it looks like you are connected to your application server, but in reality you are just connected to another temporary server. After disconnecting this server is killed.

If you want uploads on Heroku, you need to store them in some cloud storage like Amazon S3.